# Expression Engine - How do I randomly display one of the last seven entries?

Tags: expressionengine

I would like to randomly display one of the last seven entries from a particular channel. I tried using offset="" but that happens to be exactly the opposite of what I need. I also considered using a date option: only show entries after a certain date, but that would only last for a while before it had to be modified.

Any serious suggestions will be seriously considered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no great way to do this natively with expressionengine.

Check out the AB entry ids addon. here's a specific example that should be what you're looking for: http://www.addonbakery.com/docs/ab-entry-ids.html

Just add orderby="random" to the nested channel entries tag pair and limit the entry ids query to 7.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ab-entry-ids

Comment: Hi Philip, Thanks for the response. It does look promising. Do you know if it is possible to limit the display to only one of the returned items, and do that randomly?

Comment: Thanks for the response Philip. I appreciate it.